# как редактировать сообщение бота отправленное в ответ на команду (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

```
@bot.command()
async def roulette(ctx, message):
    print(message)
    await ctx.send('{0} выпадает'.format(randint(1,6)))
    for i in range(0, 10):
        print(message)
        await message.edit(content=i) # на этой строке возникает ошибка
        sleep(0.2)
```

Мысль этого вопроса - изменение последнего отправленного сообщения ботом и исправление ошибки.
Заранее спасибо :3

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция принимает 2 аргумента - `ctx` и `message`.

Первый (`ctx`) в функцию передает библиотека `Discord-py`, когда вы вызываете функцию. Это контекст команды. Из него можно получить канал, сообщение, автора, сервер и [**`другую информацию`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context).

Второй аргумент (`message`) принимает значение первого слова после `!roulette`, где `!` - префикс вашего бота. То есть, при отправке команды `!roulette сообщение1 сообщение2`, в переменную `message` будет записана строка '`сообщение1`'.

---

Ошибка возникает потому, что вы пытаетесь отредактировать не сообщение, а переменную `message`, которая является простой строкой типа `str`.

Чтобы все работало корректно, вам нужно создать объект сообщения при его первой отправке:

```
msg = await ctx.send('{0} выпадает'.format(randint(1,6)))
```

А затем изменять уже этот объект:

```
await msg.edit(content=i)
```